# How to make several instances of Nivo Slider in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, nivo-slider

I developed a web site using Drupal 7. I use Nivo Slider and it works perfectly for me. I used Nivo Slider for the front page of the site. When I configured the Nivo Slider it's settings are displayed under structure in the Drupal CMS menu. Basically, I have to update images and set transitions and etc.

I have another page where I nee to add a new slideshow, but I don't know how to make another instance of Nivo Slider and use it. I would guess there should be an easy way to handel this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create another instance of the nivo slider block with the [MultiBlock](http://drupal.org/project/multiblock) module, but the other instance will have the same settings and same images of the original slider block.

You can use the [Views Nivo Slider](http://drupal.org/project/views_nivo_slider) module to create another slider block.